# Use a js variable into a rails condition

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

How can I use a js variable into a rails search ?

I'm generating a calendar in my view (full-calendar), and I would like to see if there is an element on each day. To do that, I've created a loop in jQuery and I've created a condition to see if there is any event on this day :

```
$("#calendar").find('td').each (function() {
    if('<%= @user.events.where("end >= ?", '$(this).attr("data-date")').any? %>' == true){
        alert("true");
    }  else {
        alert("false");
    }
});
```

But this script is not correct, the js part:

```
$(this).attr('data-date')
```

into the ruby search is not compatible

Any idea for that problem?

Comment: you can make a Ajax call to rails app and show the alert based on response.

Comment: how would you do this ?

Comment: Can you please add more details what exactly you are trying to achieve if you find one or more event on that specific date?

Comment: This type of call won't work because rails can't just wait around for the jquery loop to execute before it runs its query. What you're going to have to do instead is get `@user.events` into a javascript variable and then make the function check based on that. Alternatively you can find which calendar days need to alert on the backend then create them with an attribute that you can check for, like `data-alert`